# Why does Android Contact modify have a side effect of created an (Unknown) contact entry?

Tags: android, contacts

I have a weird issue on an Android 2.2 device.  I have an existing
contact and I do a modify operation on it via:

```
ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder =
ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " +
    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?",
    new String[]{id,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE})
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,displayName)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME,familyName)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME,middleName)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME,givenName)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PREFIX,honorificPrefix)
   .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.SUFFIX,honorificSuffix);

mApp.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

The contact gets modified correctly.  All of the new values show up
for the Contacts name.

However, if I look in my Contacts app there is a new contact called
"(Unknown)" that shows up after I do a modify.  I can insert as many
contacts as I want but every modify creates a new "(Unknown)" contact.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an errant newInsert() call for the RAW_CONTACT_ID as part of the larger function which was causing the problem.  Sorry for the time wasting question.